# Aws cdk deploy not working even after bootstrapping

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I keep having the below error  when i try to do cdk deploy .. even after bootstrapping and all the necessary cloudformation template has been created in my as console

```
 ❌  tservings failed: Error: tservings: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/pen/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
at CloudFormationDeployments.validateBootstrapStackVersion (/Users/user/Documents/tservings/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:482:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (/Users/user/Documents/tservings/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:457:7)
at CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (/Users/user/Documents/tservings/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:339:7)
at CdkToolkit.deploy (/Users/user/Documents/tservings/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:209:24)
at initCommandLine (/Users/user/Documents/tservings/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cli.ts:341:12)

tservings: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/pen/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
 Task "watch" failed when executing "cdk deploy --hotswap" (cwd: /Users/user/Documents/tservings)
```

Comment: Did you change your synthesizer to modify the bootstrap qualifier? By default, the bootstrap qualifier is `hnb659fds`, not `pen`.